# What is ascent venting?

Tags: atmosphere, cubesat, terminology, materials

I am writing a report on CubeSat construction, and while reading Cal Poly's [CDS](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5418c831e4b0fa4ecac1bacd/t/62193b7fc9e72e0053f00910/1645820809779/CDS+REV14_1+2022-02-09.pdf) I encountered the concept of ascent venting (or more specifically, the constraint that 'ascent venting per ventable volume/area [must be] less than 50.8 meters (2000 inches)' - section 2.1.9 of the CDS).

What is ascent venting? And how does 'ascent venting per ventable volume/area' have a dimension of length?

Comment: Sounds vaguely like a way to ensure that areas such as the interstage section of a rocket are allowed to transition from atmospheric pressure to vacuum as the rocket ascends. But I don't have a clue about the units of measure...

Comment: different but related: [Pressure inside a launch fairing - falcon 9](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25655/12102) (3 answers) and [what kind of valves are used in payload fairing for venting?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54640/12102) (currently unanswered) and [Why not use alternative/low-pressure atmospheres in fairings during launch?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54076/12102) and [Could a fairing vacuum protect the payload from acoustic loads?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35765/12102)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ascent venting is the venting of gases during ascent. Spacecraft are typically assembled and integrated with the launch vehicle on Earth, at standard atmospheric pressures. Therefore, any gas that is trapped inside the spacecraft will be at Earth ambient pressure.

During the ascent, the pressure environment in the payload fairing very quickly changes from Earth ambient pressure to near vacuum within minutes. Any gases that are trapped inside the spacecraft must be vented in order to avoid damage to the spacecraft.

However, the vented gases need to go *somewhere*: they will thus increase the pressure in the payload fairing (or whatever container the spacecraft is contained in, e.g., a space tug or satellite dispenser). This container itself only has limited capabilities to vent the gases. Therefore, the venting needs to be limited.

The limit is set based on the surface area of the spacecraft, i.e., the spacecraft is allowed to vent a certain volume of gas per surface area of the spacecraft.

Volume divided by area is length.

Comment: Ah yes, I understand now - however, I still don't get the dimensions. If the quantity is ascent venting _per_ ventable volume/area, shouldn't it be in units of $m^{-1}$?

Comment: In this case, "per" means "based on". The venting that occurs during ascent is based on volume/area which gives the answer in units of length which must be smaller than 50.8 m.

Comment: Ok, that's what I am getting stuck on - I have been reading it as _per_ as in 'for each', which is where I was getting my dimensions mixed up. I understand now.

Comment: It's not the surface area of the spacecraft, but the surface area of the openings between the interior and exterior. For a 1U CubSat, enclosed volume at most 1000 cm^3, an area of 0.2 cm^2 suffices. No a difficult requirement: few are so thoroughly enclosed.

Comment: I'm not quite following. Both the fairing cavity and the satellite start out at 1 atm. During ascent the outside pressure decreases, so the fairing vents and the pressure inside the fairing cavity decreases. This causes the satellite to vent. Pressure decreases in the satellite as it tries to match the cavity pressure. It might have trouble keeping up with the fairing's venting, which could cause a problem for the satellite, thus fairing venting is purposely limited.  But if the satellite vents easier than the fairing does, then the satellite pressure will always equal the fairing pressure.

Comment: @Steve my understanding is that if the venting ratio is too large, then the satellite's internal volume is significantly larger than its venting area and thus may risk a building pressure differential as the fairing depressurises, which I imagine may be dangerous. I think the vent ratio limit is not to prevent the satellite from venting too well, but rather not well enough.

Comment: @moooligan - that's what I am assuming also. If the fairing cavity pressure drops faster than the satellite is able to vent, then the pressure differential between the satellite internal pressure and the cavity pressure increases, creating sort of a ballooning effect inside the satellite that can overstress the structure. However if the satellite vents as well as or better than the fairing, then there is no pressure differential. Or if the satellite vents at least well enough to keep the differential within limits. So I'm still not understanding why satellite venting is being constrained.

Comment: @Steve - yes, I agree. I think that the constraint being discussed is on the upper limit of the ascent venting, ie. constraining the minimum venting rate of the satellite to prevent the ballooning effect you mention. What initially confused me is that this definition of ascent venting is inverse to the 'venting rate' of the satellite; a larger ascent venting value corresponds to a larger volume/venting-area ratio (ie. worse venting), thus the ascent venting must be bound from above to ensure safety. I don't think there is any constraint on the satellite venting too well.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: PLF Volume / **Vent**  Area = linear

“Volume” is the payload fairing (PLF) – volume of payload

“Area” is the area of the vent(s)

For instance,

- if the PLF is 2m diameter and 2m long, its volume is just over 6m^3
- and the vent(s) have a combined area of 0.1 m^2
- then the ratio would be 60m

A previous answer stated the “area” was the “surface area of the spacecraft” but it makes more sense that it would be vent area.